# Working with SQL Azure from Starbucks

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a SQL Azure database. For some reason, I can work with it when I'm at home, but not when I'm at Starbucks. I can successfully login to it and "manage" it via the web-based tool provided from the Windows Azure Portal. However:

1. When my web app tries to hit the database, I receive an error that says:

   *The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.*
2. When I try to hit the database from SQL Management Studio, I receive the following error:

> *Cannot connect to tcp:[serverName],[number].
>
>       A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10060)*

I know my IP Address is unblocked, because as mentioned, I can use the web-based tool. I know the database is setup properly, because I can use it from home. However, when I seem to try to work from any local coffee shop, I'm stuck.

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the exact same situation. Glad to see I'm not going crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Web based Azure Portal doesn't use your local IP address to connect to your databases, it uses the ip address of the server hosting the portal.

since you're getting a new IP from coffee shops, either you add that in the Azure SQL Firewall or you open up your Azure SQL to all IPs.

if that doesn't work, then maybe your local coffee shop has firewall setting blocking port 1433...